# How to pass credential to NiFi rest api

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

I have enabled LDAP authentication for Apache NiFi-1.1.1.

I can able to access NiFi web UI after logged in with LDAP user.

When I try to access REST API with basic authentication `/process-groups/root`, it shows

`Unable to perform the desired action due to insufficient permissions. Contact the system administrator.`

- How to pass credential to NiFi REST API?
- How to access NiFi REST API with the token?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When authenticating via LDAP, the NiFi REST API will require the client pass along a token with each request. To obtain a token, you'll need to pass the credentials to authenticate.

```
curl 'https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/access/token' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' --data 'username=<user>&password=<pass>' --compressed
```

This request will return the token that you'll need to pass in the headers of each subsequent request. For instance:

```
curl 'https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/flow/current-user' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' --compressed
```

Comment: This is an old question, but I am trying this and getting an error because my password has a '%' in it. How can I get around this issue? The script I'm writing prompts for user credentials so I have no way of knowing ahead of time if I need to escape any characters.

Comment: @Josh if you can use Python for your automation, then there is a set of functions in [NyPyApi](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/blob/master/nipyapi/demo/secure_connection.py) to assist with secured access, including correctly encoding strings passed to the API.
I have linked the demo in the code for this, but the general project may also be useful (I'm one of the authors)

Comment: @Chaffelson Firstly, great job on the NyPyApi. 

I have been trying to use it against a Apache Knox secured NIFI cluster. Cookie/Browser based authentication seems to work perfectly on my cluster. However NyPyApi does not seem to able to get the token required for accessing other endpoints. Are you aware of resources to enable this config. I am quite sure there are some missing configs at my end, but do not know what. 

And again, thanks for all the work.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words - I see you asked this question and got a response directly from the NiFi dev team, I hope it's working well for you!