# How to connect to rest endpoints of a secure Apache NiFi instance

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi instance running which is set up to support OIDC authentication. I am builiding a secondary UI application that internally accesses NiFi REST API. How do I authenticate my end users with the target NiFi instance?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried it but I think you can follow the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835487/10872037 (i.e. get an access token from your OIDC server then pass this token within an `Authorization` header in your request)